# simplest explanation of $query->row() and $query->result()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm quite annoyed with CI's behavior lately, may be because i'm little ignorant towards small stuff, now to the question :D. i'm making an application where i'm trying to get one single row using active records, now as a good programmer(i think) i try this
when i select such as login

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1)
{
    // do something
}
// now when i make an update, that also a single row i tend to use this command
if($query->affected_rows() == 1)
{
   // perform some action
}
// now i use this code when i've to get all entries of one single user
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   // show them
}
```

now many time i get error like "Call to member function num_rows() on non object"
can anyone please explain what to use, when to use and how to use, so that code igniter never gets made a me

Comment: Your error is cause the query failed. Try var_dump($query) when you get that error and see what properties the returned object (if any) has. You may be better off saying `if($query && $query->num_rows())` which sounds verbose and unnecessary. It could also be that you're running queries that are not constructed well. We would need examples to know further

Comment: it's either better of or unnecessary. I vote for the latter.

Comment: this has *nothing* to do with CI, it's how PHP works. fix the query.

Comment: could please explain the basic functioning, how to use, when to use them, since i don't know how they are used, i just use them blindly, i wish i know the proper function so i could use them

Comment: $query needs to be available. once you are out of the method, unless you returned query it will not be available. if that doesn't make sense, show us an example that includes ALL the code of where its failing.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.num_rows()
```

num_rows() are `result helper functions`, they are used against a `query resultobject`, note that we `don't use` it like `$this->db->num_rows()`, instead we use it like:

```
$query = $this-query('query');
```

OR

```
$query = $this->db->get('tableName');

if($query->num_rows()>0){ ....}
```

Now lets see affected_rowS().

```
2. affected_rows()
```

affected_rows is a `query helper function`, they are used like `$this->db->affected_rows()`. Note that `$this->db->affected_rows()` yields valid result only after a valid db `write` operation. i.e insert, update and delete. The database class has a small hack that allows it to return the correct number of affected rows after a delete operation because MySQL "DELETE FROM TABLE" returns 0 affected rows.

```
3.$query->result()
```

This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure.
i.e if you have more than one result you have to `loop the result object` like :

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){....}

4.$query->row()
```

This function returns a single result row as an object.  If your query has more than one row, it `returns only the first row`.

I hope my explanation is readable enough.. Although you could find all of these in CI docs with relevant examples.